# The most concise way to parse a string into hash in powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I wonder what is the most concise way to parse a certain string into a hash in Powershell.

Here is what I have so far:

```
PS D:\Videos> $x
Track ID 1: audio (AC3/EAC3) [number:2 uid:1938239150 codec_id:A_AC3 codec_private_length:0 language:heb default_track:1 forced_track:0 enabled_track:1 default_duration:32000000 audio_sampling_frequency:48000 audio_channels:6]

PS D:\Videos> $hash = @{}

PS D:\Videos> $x -match "^.*\[(.*)\]" | ForEach-Object { $Matches[1] -split ' ' |% { $tmp = $_ -split ':'; $hash[$tmp[0]] = $tmp[1] } }

PS D:\Videos> $hash

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                         
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                         
audio_sampling_frequency       48000                                                                                                                                                         
codec_private_length           0                                                                                                                                                             
audio_channels                 6                                                                                                                                                             
number                         2                                                                                                                                                             
default_duration               32000000                                                                                                                                                      
forced_track                   0                                                                                                                                                             
enabled_track                  1                                                                                                                                                             
language                       heb                                                                                                                                                           
codec_id                       A_AC3                                                                                                                                                         
uid                            1938239150                                                                                                                                                    
default_track                  1                                                                                                                                                             



PS D:\Videos>
```

It does the job, but seems to me there should be a shorter way.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possibility:

```
$string = 'Track ID 1: audio (AC3/EAC3) [number:2 uid:1938239150 codec_id:A_AC3 codec_private_length:0 language:heb default_track:1 forced_track:0 enabled_track:1 default_duration:32000000 audio_sampling_frequency:48000 audio_channels:6]'
$Hash = ConvertFrom-StringData ($string -replace '^.+\[(.+)\]','$1').replace(':','=').replace(' ',"`n")
$Hash



Name                           Value                                                                          
----                           -----                                                                          
enabled_track                  1                                                                              
codec_id                       A_AC3                                                                          
default_duration               32000000                                                                       
audio_channels                 6                                                                              
uid                            1938239150                                                                     
language                       heb                                                                            
default_track                  1                                                                              
audio_sampling_frequency       48000                                                                          
forced_track                   0                                                                              
number                         2                                                                              
codec_private_length           0
```

Answer (score 3):

For this particular case this code is somewhat shorter:

```
$hash = @{}
foreach($m in [regex]::Matches($x, '(\w+):(\w+)')) {
    $hash[$m.Groups[1].Value] = $m.Groups[2].Value
}
$hash
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$t="Track ID 1: audio (AC3/EAC3) [number:2 uid:1938239150 codec_id:A_AC3 codec_private_length:0 language:heb default_track:1 forced_track:0 enabled_track:1 default_duration:32000000 audio_sampling_frequency:48000 audio_channels:6]"

$h=@{}
foreach($record in $t.Split('[]')[1].Split(' ')) {
    $key, $value = $record.Split(':')
    $h.$key=$value
}
$h
```